# Calculated fieds in python django

Tags: python, django, django-models, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I have a Table in my database with fields `id`, `body_temp`, and `status`, and its defined by the following class:

```
class Temperature(models.Model):
    ...
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    body_temp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
```

the field `body_temp` will be populated by means of a form, on the other hand, I want the field `status` to store a string based on the value entered in the field `body_temp`.
if the temperature value entered in the field `body_temp` is less than 38, I want the field `status` to store a string `normal`.
However, if the temperature value entered in the field `body_temp` is greater or eaqual to 38, I want the field `status` to store a string `suspect`.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your status field as a property, then it will be calculated on the fly

```
class Temperature(models.Model):
    ...
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    body_temp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)

    @property
    def status(self):
        if self.body_temp < 38:
            return 'normal'
        else:
            return 'suspect'
```

Or you can [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) save() method to calculate this field on any edit and store result in DB

```
class Temperature(models.Model):
    ...
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    body_temp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.body_temp < 38:
            self.status = 'normal'
        else:
            self.status = 'suspect'
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```